# htaccess problem. one rule works, other doesnt

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problem with htaccess rewriting. Im creating a simple forum.

the rule for fcategory works and rewrites url.
but the rule for ftopic doesnt. (object not found error 404). What could be the problem?

Here is php code:

```
<?php
require "includes/header.php";

// Forum topic list.
if (isset($_GET["fcategory"])) {
    $category_id = $_GET["fcategory"];
  foreach($handler->query("SELECT * FROM forum_topics WHERE category_id = '$category_id' ORDER BY id DESC") as $row) {
        echo "<div class='forum_topic_title'><h1><a href='".$host."/ftopic/".$row['id']."/".$row['topic_title_seo']."'>".$row['topic_title']."</a></h1></div>";
  }

}
// Forum post content.
else if (isset($_GET["ftopic"])) {
  $topic_id = $_GET["ftopic"];
  foreach($handler->query("SELECT * FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id' ORDER BY id DESC") as $row) {
    echo "<div class='forum_post_content'>".$row['post_content']."</div>";
  }
}
// Forum category list.
else {
  foreach($handler->query("SELECT * FROM forum_categories ORDER BY id DESC") as $row) {
    echo "<div class='forum_category_title'><h1><a href='".$host."/fcategory/".$row['id']."/".$row['category_title_seo']."'>".$row['category_title']."</a></h1></div>";
    echo "<div class='forum_category_description'>".$row['category_description']."</div>";
  }
}

require "includes/footer.php";
?>
```

And htaccess code:

```
# Turn Rewrite Engine On
# NC makes the rule non case sesnitive
# L makes this the last rule that this specific condition will match
# Rewrite for custom.php?article=xxxxx

RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for index.php
RewriteRule ^index index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+) index.php?article=$1 [NC,L]


# Rewrite for forum.php
RewriteRule ^forum forum.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^fcategory/([0-9]+) forum.php?fcategory=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^ftopic([0-9]+) forum.php?ftopic=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Looks like you missed the slash between `ftopic` and `([0-9]+)` in your pattern in that last rule.

Comment: Oh im so embarrassed! :D Thank you!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index index.php [NC,L]` will certainly create a rewrite loop. `RewriteRule ^forum forum.php [NC,L]` likewise.